# Not handling missing details, response False

Tags: reactjs, ajax, axios

How can one check if, let's say alert when a title does not exist?

Can this be achieved with Axios?

[image]

```
export const getMoviesImdb = async (title) => {
  title = encodeURIComponent(title);
  return fetch(`http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=${title}`)
  .then((response) => response.json()
      .then((data) => {
        if (data.Response != "False") {
          return data.Search
        }
        return Promise.reject(data.Message);
      }, [])
      .catch((error) => {
        return Promise.reject(error); 
      })
  );
};
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With axios, you can access result using `response.data`. Also, it already returns a promise, so you don't have to explicitely return promise. Instead make checks on api response and throw error and simply catch it in the usage(where you call the `getMoviesImdb` function). Finally, the `getMoviesImdb` fun need not to be an async fun.

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/axios-react-refactored-code-4xejx?file=/src/App.js) (just add your api key in the url to test it)

**Code snippet sample**

```js
export default function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    let myMovies;
    getMoviesImdb("asdf")
      .then(res => {
        // make sure to use your api key to see results
        console.log("res", res);
        myMovies = res;
      })
      .catch(err => {
        // make sure to use your api key to see error message
        console.log("err", err);
      });
  }, []);

  const getMoviesImdb = title => {
    console.log("title", title);
    // title = encodeURIComponent(title);
    // use your api key below
    return axios(`http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=${title}`).then(response => {
      // console.log("response", response);
      if (response.data.Response !== "False") {
        return data.Search;
      }
      console.log("response.data", response.data.Error);
      throw new Error(response.data.Error);
    });
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```